# Semantic markup for responsive docblocks

Tags: html, css, semantics, semantic-markup, responsive-design

I'm working on some codex like documentation [here](http://responsejs.com/#methods) and I want to write the markup so that it looks like a [docblock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc) For example:

```
@param   string    lastName     the last name of the person

@param   string    firstName    the first name of the person

@return  string
```

I'm trying to figure out what are the most semantic elements to use (e.g. `pre` or `dl` or `table` or a combination of `div` and `span`) and I also want to make it responsive, so that in small screens via CSS it would look like:

```
@param   
string    
lastName     
the last name of the person

@param
string
firstName
the first name of the person

@return
string
```

I've used 2 solutions for this before. The first uses `pre` with that has some `br` tags in it which are set to `display:none` above a certain breakpoint. The other is using a `table` and a media query like:

```
@media all and (max-width:640px) {
    table,thead,tbody,tfoot,th,td,tr{display:block}
    tr+tr{margin-top:1em}
}
```

I'm open to any other ideas too. What do you think is the most semantic way that is also able to be styled responsively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more experimenting, markup like this IMO is the best hybrid of semantic + responsive + cross-browser compatibility. It gives you a lot of CSS flexiblity:

```
<dl>
  <dt><b>@param</b> <em>string</em> <strong>first</strong></dt>
  <dd>is the first name</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
  <dt><b>@param</b> <em>string</em> <strong>last</strong></dt>
  <dd>is the last name</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
  <dt><b>@return</b> <em>string</em></dt>
  <dd></dd>
</dl>
```

with CSS like:

```
dt,dd {display:inline-block;*display:inline;margin:.5em 0}
dd {margin-left:1em}
```